# Official Syntax reference for asciidoc in github

Tags: github, asciidoc

I try to create a documentation using asciidoc; currently working with visual studio code extension joaompinto.asciidoctor-vscode. But when uploading the files to github, git seems to ignore most formatings. For example, I already experienced, that github does not support include and putting a list in a block

```
====

* Entry1

* Entry2

====
```

does not create any formating grouping this list in a container.

Is there any documentation for asciidoc, only describing those things, that are usable by github?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it helps but I had a similar problem with asciidoc table of contents in github and I found the following page:

https://github.com/opendevise/asciidoc-samples/blob/master/demo.adoc

raw page available here for syntax examples:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/opendevise/asciidoc-samples/master/demo.adoc

and it really helped.